# Why is my dynamically created label failing to align as desired?

Tags: c#, label, panel

When I set a label's ContentAlignment property to MiddleRight, I expect it to align to the right within the panel on which I place it. Instead, it stubbornly stays put aligned left. Why is this, and how can I fix it? Here's my code:

```
private void CreateNewLabel(int YPos, string DisplayStr, ContentAlignment contentAlign,
                            int FontSize)
{
    Label lbl = new Label();
    //lbl.Left = DEFAULT_XPOS;
    lbl.Font = new Font(lbl.Font.Name, FontSize, lbl.Font.Style);
    lbl.Top = YPos;
    lbl.Text = DisplayStr;
    lbl.TextAlign = contentAlign;
    lbl.AutoSize = true;
    panelFauxLabel.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

Everything is working EXCEPT horizontal placement. I don't want to set the Left property, because I want certain alignments to take up all the "right side" space they can; calculating the XPos is possible, I'm sure, but also quite complicated, I'm even more sure.

### UPDATE

Olivier's answer worked just fine. The code is now:

```
    private void CreateNewLabel(int YPos, string DisplayStr, ContentAlignment contentAlign, int FontSize)
    {
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Left = DEFAULT_XPOS;
        lbl.Font = new Font(lbl.Font.Name, FontSize, lbl.Font.Style);
        lbl.Top = YPos;
        lbl.Text = DisplayStr;
        lbl.TextAlign = contentAlign;
        if (contentAlign.Equals(ContentAlignment.MiddleRight))
        {
            lbl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right;
        }
        else // there is no AnchorStyles.Center or AnchorStyles.Middle
        {
            lbl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left;
        }
        lbl.AutoSize = false;
        lbl.Width = panelFauxLabel.Width;
        panelFauxLabel.Controls.Add(lbl);
    }
```

### UPDATE 2

I had to add a tweak to the height of the label to prevent large font sizes from being chopped off at the knees, so to speak:

```
    // This factor was just a guess, but it seems to work pretty well
    double down = Math.Round(FontSize*1.5);
    lbl.Height = Convert.ToInt32(down);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextAlign` aligns the text within the label, not the label within the panel. Consider using the `Anchor` property in order to align the label to the right edge of the panel.

---

**UPDATE**

Here's how this can be done: Make the label the same width than the panel, anchor the label to the top, left and right

```
lbl.TextAlign = contentAlign;
lbl.AutoSize = false;
lbl.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
lbl.Top = YPos;
lbl.Left = 0;
lbl.Width = panelFauxLabel.ClientSize.Width; // ClientSize takes account of scroll
                                             // bars, borders and padding.
panelFauxLabel.Controls.Add(lbl);
```

Now the label resizes together with the panel and the text aligns correctly within the label. Set `lbl.AutoSize` to `false` in order to make the label size independent of the text length.

Comment: I've added a concrete example.